# is try/catch in php always working fine?

Tags: php, mongodb

i try to handle exception and write code as follows but i also get exception when document save sucessfully in my databse.

```
$table = "MyRequestTable";
$smsID = new MongoId();
$data = array("_id" => $smsID,
            "requestUserid" => 2500,
            "requestDate" => new MongoDate(strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))),
            "requestNosSms" => 1
        );
try
{
     $result = $table->insert($data, array("safe" => TRUE)); 
     echo $smsID ;
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

i got following exception
"Invalid modifier specified: $push"

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. You need to understand your code better.

Comment: Yea it isn't this code that is causing the problem, you need to get back to that debugger I am afraid

Comment: Your code is weird. You are assigning $table to a string, but then treating it like a object?
"Invalid modifier" exceptions come from the database, so your document wasn't updated properly.
Also, your code and the exception message don't match.. What exactly is the code that caused the exception?

Answer (score 2):

Even if `INSERT` command executed correct may be situation when some other instruction throws exception. Are you sure that other parts of code are correct?